# Accessing value of element in view from controller in MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

In View i have

```
@Html.TextArea("ChangeStatusCommentTxt")
```

In controller i tried to access it by

```
Request["ChangeStatusCommentTxt"];
```

it is returning value

But when i use

```
@Html.TextArea("ChangeStatusCommentTxt",new{@class="someclass"});
```

it is not returning value!! why is that?

Comment: You would need to use the M part of MVC. A great place to start is http://www.asp.net/mvc

Comment: how can i add class to textbox without using any model? I want an empty text box with css applied using class

Comment: you can try to access data from  FormCollection , and if you are adding a class or css try to inspect rendered html . it may help.

Comment: how to add class to the text area?

Comment: are you using a model for your view ?
new {@class="..."} seems OK to add your class html attribute

Comment: Please check the question, now the problem is different!

Comment: @EmmanuelM. ya it is adding but i am not able to get value if i do that!

Comment: can you show the controler action called on submit (to check your action parameters)
TextAreaFor => bind to the model by field name
TextArea => just generate HTML